# Url and app indexing schemes in 2017

Tags: android, url-scheme, android-app-indexing, firebase-app-indexing

How should url schemes for android be designed nowadays. Is it still recommended to use `android-app://` as a scheme for *private* app-indexed in-app content, which is not exposed online?

The firebase [app-indexing sample source](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/app-indexing/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml#L32-L34) just uses

`https://www.example.com/articles/`

while the [official android docu](https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/enabling-app-indexing.html) says

> The deep links that you share with Google Search must take this URI format:

`android-app://<package_name>/<scheme>/<host_path>`

As far as I can tell, both work - but what is the officially approved best practice?